# Using scp to copy multiple files and rename each one

Tags: linux, scp

I need many image files from a remote server, each in a different directory `dir_A`, `dir_B`... etc  but all with the same name `image.png`. I therefore need to rename each file as I copy it. Can I achieve this with a single command?

Answer (score -1):

You can use following bash script to achieve this:

```
while true; do
    echo "Remote File Path: "
    read path
    scp $path "image-$RANDOM.jpg"
done;
```

Path should be fully qualified resource locator similar to *server.com:/home/user/image.jpg*

Comment: do you know if this will work if I need a password to access the remote server?

Comment: yes it will, but each time it will ask for password!